# How to count the Json elements in the response

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

The service returns json in the following format :

```
    [
    "ABC",
    "HELLO",
    "GOODBYE"
    ]
```

How can I count the number of strings inside the json?

Comment: That is an array. Just use array.length to find out the number of elements.

Comment: Is it a json array then?

Comment: you need a json parser. It will tell you how many elements are in a json array. There are few on the net, i.e. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: if it' unmarshaled from JSON ( String) to the object array it will be possible to call `.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Json parser like GSON, to deserialize the JSON.

```
// Deserialization
int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class); 
// ==> ints2 will be same as ints
System.out.println(int2.length);
```

see https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Array-Examples

Comment: `String[] myList = gson.fromJson("[\"one\", \"two\", \"three\"]", String[].class)` I believe that would be how to deserialize a list of strings